# What happens when .NET isn't installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, .net-framework, .net-4.0

I know the .NET runtime is required to run .NET apps. I know that on Windows 8, the OS will detect that it needs a specific version and install it before the app runs, but what happens on Windows 7?

Will the app just crash with no good explanation, or gracefully with a prompt to install .NET?

If it matters, I'm wondering about 4.0. I'm assuming that the computer has Windows 7 and its automatic updates installed as well as SP1.

Comment: If the required version of .NET Framework isn't installed then the .NET program  can't run just like if the required version of Java isn't installed.  If its setup to install automatic updates then it literally will always have .NET Framework unless the owner makes a habit of getting rid of it.  If you are writing software that requires it, bundle the setup with your software, then you always know the user will have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows will present an error message if the proper framework is not installed.  Here is a screenshot of the error message I got when I tried to run an .NET 4.0 app on Windows 7 without .NET 4.

[image: Error Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Dot net should be installed by default. In windows 7, 3.5 should be there by default. In Win8 4.0 should be there by default. If you need 4, install 4.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Comment: Also, sometimes programs need a specific major version of .NET, and you wind up installing it anyway even though there's a newer version present.